# Need information on Kafka time based retention at topic level

Tags: apache-kafka

looking for the details while updating retention.ms and below is the scenario

1. created topic t1 with retention.ms 6 hrs
2. produces 10 messages
3. After 2 hrs, modified retention.ms to 24 hrs.
4. produces 10 messages

Question: does this change application to earlier messages(10 messages produced 2 hrs earlier-step-2)? OR it is applicable to newly produced messages only(messages of step 4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The retention is applied on the topic level. As long as you increase the topic retention before messages have been deleted (i.e old retention has passed), the retention will apply to them as well. 
so given your example, the answer is YES, the first 10 messages(step 2) will be retained for another 22 hours (24h - 2h), and the last 10 messages (step 4) will be retained for another 24 hours

Comment: All messages will be retained as long as the segment is not closed, though

Answer (score 1):

You can modify retention for already existing topic and it will be apply to all messages, that are stored by Kafka (for old and new).
You can both decrease and increase `retention.ms` property.

Frequency that logs cleaner checks if logs are eligible for deletion describe by `log.retention.check.interval.ms` property (it is broker property). If your `retention.ms` is much lower than `log.retention.check.interval.ms`, you might see some lags.

Also there is other case, when logs might be deleted later than `retention.ms`. 
Kafka keeps messages in segments. 
Cleaning is applied to whole segment, not to particular message.
If segments are *big* (`log.segment.bytes`, `segment.bytes`) and messages are appended in-frequently enough to not exceed `retention.ms` of the last added message, messages might be kept few times longer than `retention.ms` suggests.

Default value for `segment.bytes` is `1073741824`, 
so depending on message size, you have to produce from thousands to millions of messages to close the log segment, 
thus causing records to be eligible for removing.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't hurt to mention that by default, 10-20 messages isn't enough to close a log segment, thus causing records to be removed